# Is there a word/phrase/idiom to describe the feeling of you facing a dilemma?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, idiom-requests

I've got "running backward on a cornfield" as an answer on Reddit... there aren't enough usages of it online so I'm not quite sure what it actually means...

are there any alternatives?

Comment: Need more context, what kind of feeling?

Comment: Gored by the horns of a dilemma.

Comment: @HotLicks - Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

"Between a rock and a hard place" can be used to describe a dilemma wherein you must choose between two negative options. It might work, depending on the type of dilemma you wish to describe.

Answer (score 1):

•Between two fires/ 
•in a fix/
•in a quandary/
•between the devil and the deep sea/
•between Scylla and Charybdis

-- may be used to mean a state of indecision.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought of the "rock and a hard place" suggestion of Mar Zum as well, but one problem with that is that it relates to a dilemma in which there are only negative outcomes. It's equally possible to be caught in a dilemma which has potentially positive outcomes, such as a choice between two jobs, two lovers, two holiday destinations...

Consequently unless the dilemma is of the negative type, I'd take a look at [conflicted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conflict?q=Conflicted#conflict__10), which seems to cover both.

> (as adjective conflicted) Having or showing confused and mutually
>   inconsistent feelings:

Comment: +1 for conflicted. I think it conveys well the *feeling* of facing a dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

'Betwixt and between' could be useful

Answer (score 0):

***in a quandary*** would be quite apt.

Comment: I agree, but remember that this site serves a global audience, and while native speakers would all recognize this term, people who have English as a second language might not, and without support, evidence, citations to authority (read: a quote from a dictionary), they have no way to know whether they can believe you, or use this suggestion.