# A single word for "stuck between a rock and a hard place"

Tags: single-word-requests

[expression "caught between a rock and a hard place"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32785/102076) describes the meaning and origins. I'm looking for a single word that means the same thing.

The answer mentions the word "dilemma". This fits, but to me it would usually just suggest that there is a problem, rather than being in a situation where you need to choose between two bad options. I also found "quandary" and "predicament". I don't think these fit well, either.

Are there any words that work better?

Examples:

> This left me between a rock and a hard place.
>
> This left me in a dilemma/predicament/quandary.

Comment: You could just say, "This left me stuck."

Comment: To me that would suggest having no options, rather than two bad ones

Comment: Have a look at the definition of dilemma in a dictionary. It doesn't just mean problem. It means almost exactly what you want the word to mean. https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=dilemma+meaning

Comment: when you are stuck between a rock and a hard place, you are stuck. I've just shortened the explanation of why you are stuck.  But I agree with @chaslyfromUK- a dilemma is perfect.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I did look, the trouble there is that it CAN also just mean "problem", as I have described in my question.

Comment: A dilemma means you don't know what choice to make.

Comment: @jim yes, that is certainly one definition. Another is simply "any difficult or perplexing situation or problem". I am looking for a word where there will be no ambiguity.

Comment: How about some real context?  You say, "This left me between a rock and a hard place."  What is the 'this'? If we had a real example showing how many choices there were we could give a real answer.

Comment: A good example would be the origin story in the linked question

Comment: @rjdown- Hopefully the context in which you use this word will eliminate the ambiguity.  But even still, the use of *dilemma* to simply mean a problem (and not one where you have to make a choice between two undesirable alternatives) is *really* rare.   "Could you help me with my calculus dilemma" would not be taken as needing help on a problem 17, but would be taken as a *should-I-take-it-this-semester-or-next* type of a problem.

Comment: @jim I am not convinced. Oxford describes this usage as "widespread and generally acceptable"

Comment: I'm not convinced either.  Even in the "*insoluable dilemma of adolescence*" it's a *what-should-be-done* type of a problem.  And again, if you supply any bit of context there should be no confusion.

Comment: I agree context will help. The word I'm looking for should not need any. Imagine a book title, for example. Or the suggestion of two bad choices, without explaining what they are.

Comment: I don't know that it's helpful (not being a single word), but a 'dilemma' is also known as a 'horned syllogism'. This conveys the 'two bad choices' aspect. A 'paradox' might also work, but for that you'd need a modifier because the paradox need not present two bad choices.

Comment: LOL:  http://english.stackexchange.com/a/257718/60968

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not a *[conundrum](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=conundrum)*

> A paradoxical, insoluble, or difficult problem; a dilemma: "the conundrum ... of achieving full employment without inflation" (Arthur M. Schlesinger, Jr.)

*American Heritage Dictionary*

And while not a single word, the phrase *[double bind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/double-bind)* seems to fit

> A situation in which a person is confronted with two irreconcilable demands or a choice between two undesirable courses of action.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I think double bind is going to work best for me. Not one word but good enough, thanks!

Comment: Both of these don't technically meet the single word requirement of the original question (even though its the approved answer!) because they are nouns.   The phrase "stuck between a rock and a hard place" is an adjective.  In order to turn "conundrum" into an adjectival phrase, you need to add more words, like "facing a conundrum".

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is "***conflicted***".

> to be confused about what choice to make, especially when the decision
>   involves strong beliefs or opinions

Depending on the situation, these might work:

> This left me between a rock and a hard place.
>
> This left me in a dilemma.
>
> This left me conflicted.

Answer (score 1):

*Between Scylla and Charybdis* is an older form of the same expression.  This refers to the straits of Messina between mainland Italy and Sicily, and the term **dire straits** (although admittedly two words) still sums up the situation quite well.

Comment: I think that's 4 words.

Comment: This was mentioned in the linked question. It is certainly a bit shorter, but I'm really looking for a single word, if one exists!

Comment: @rjdown "in dire straits" is my best effort answer, because the term doesn't refer to making a choice between two bad alternatives, but the near impossible task of avoiding two bad alternatives

Comment: @Jim I meant "dire straits" is two words

Comment: Hmmm, ok, it's buried in your answer with no emphasis.  I just saw "Between Scylla and Charybdis"

Comment: @Jim thanks for pointing it out.  I edited to emphasize my two versions of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using a single word, you may say "I was **squeezed**".

> "To squeeze" means to exert pressure to force someone into a difficult
>   situation.
>
> Example: Small ​businesses are being squeezed by ​heavy ​taxation.

*When playing bridge, a squeeze is a strategy that forces the opponent to "choose" what part of his defense he will renounce*.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest 'pestled', the verbal adjective (or whichever form of the verb you might have a use for) from 'pestle':

> 1. trans. To beat, pound, or grind with or as with a pestle. Also in extended use.
>      ...
> 2. intr. To use or work with a pestle.

["pestle, v.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141773?rskey=e0VuKk&result=5&isAdvanced=false (accessed November 04, 2015).]

Your use, as you example it, would be an "extended use", and perhaps so far extended as to be figurative:

> This left me **pestled**.

Use of this word would suggest the *rock and hard place* imagery without spelling it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's two words (and it's a noun), but one possible term is "[Sophie's choice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_choice)."

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word but a pretty explicit idiom...

***a no-win situation***

> A no-win situation, also called a ***lose-lose situation***, is one
>   where a person has choices, but no choice leads to a net gain. For
>   example, if an executioner offers the condemned the choice of dying by
>   being hanged, shot, or poisoned, since all choices lead to death, the
>   condemned is in a no-win situation. This bleak situation gives the
>   chooser little room: whatever choice is made, the person making it
>   will lose their life. Less drastic situations might also be considered
>   no-win situations: if one has a choice for lunch between a ham
>   sandwich and a roast beef sandwich, but is a vegetarian or has a wheat
>   allergy, that might be considered a no-win situation.
>   [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation)

Comment: This is a 3-word noun suggestion for a 1-word adjective request...

Answer (score 0):

How about "***stymied***"?

> **stymied** is a past tense form of **stymie**: to ​prevent something from
>   ​happening or someone from ​achieving a ​purpose

It's missing the element of there being precisely two equally bad alternatives, but at least it is a single word adjective that describes the situation.

This left me between a rock and a hard place.

This left me in a dilema.

This left me stymied.

Answer (score 0):

"Horns of a dilemma, faced with two equally undesirable alternatives. In Greek logic a lemma was a premise, a matter taken for granted in an argument, whereas a dilemma (a double lemma) was an either/or proposition. The Romans called this an argumentum cornutum, or “horned argument,” because one could be caught on either horn."

Comment: Is this a quote from somewhere? If so, where?