# A less metaphorical word for 'losing game'?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you have two options to chose between and either would not benefit you, so whichever you chose will be bad.

Like the word 'destined' with a more permanent bad destination.

> <sup>Example:</sup>
> It would make no difference to choose X over Y, they would both kill me. It was a **(word)**

Comment: I would say you are caught [between Scylla and Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) (or one of the alternatives listed there)

Comment: And please provide a sample sentence or two. And allowing 'phrases' would be helpful too.

Comment: *It was **hopeless***.

Comment: "_a losing proposition_", or "_not a proposition_"

Comment: Related to, but not quite the same as: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/285003/87426

Comment: I'll throw in a few that haven't been mentioned yet: "it's a no-win situation";  "it's lose-lose"; "it's 'damned if you do, damned if you don't'; "it's a Catch-22."

Comment: How about [conundrum](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/conundrum)?

Comment: How about Kobayashi Maru... Although that's still pretty metaphorical.

Comment: @rosslh That's funny how in French we use "*from Charybdis to Scylla*" to say "*from bad to worse*"

Comment: Minor nit-pick: the use of "game" here isn't really a metaphor.  A game is a conceptual framework for analyzing a scenario by identifying the possible actions of the involved parties (the "rules") and what the outcomes of these actions would be ("winning/losing").  Calling a situation a "losing game" is quite literal.

Comment: @Lawrence:  "Hobson's choice" usually denotes more of a "take it or leave it" situation, rather than requiring a choice between two bad options.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good point. Original comment deleted.

Comment: Less polite phrase : "I'm fucked either way".

Comment: Definitely metaphorical, but just stumbled across this ancient Greek idiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Though not exactly a single word, consider the expression [**lose-lose situation**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lose-Lose+Situation) (also known as **no-win situation**):

> a situation in which a favorable outcome is impossible; you are bound to lose whatever you do

Your example:

> It makes no difference to choose X over Y. They both will kill me. It's **a lose-lose situation**.

Comment: Although it's less formal, you can also just use **lose-lose** on its own:  "They both will kill me.  It's lose-lose."

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That's a very good point. The word **lose-lose** on its own is an adjective: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lose-lose

Comment: I thought lose-lose is more when neither side has anything to win. Like a stalemate only both sides lose. Is that not right?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, that's also one possible meaning. Please, don't forget that expressions that are informal in nature usually are very difficult to define precisely.

Answer (score 13):

A whole phrase **Between a rock and a hard place**

> In difficulty, faced with a choice between two unsatisfactory options.

[phrase finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place.html)

Comment: I hardly think that counts as "less metaphorical"!

Answer (score 10):

Consider ***checkmate***:

> 2. *(figuratively, by extension)* Any losing situation with no escape; utter defeat.
>
> <sub>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/checkmate)</sub>

It is still metaphorical, but a sentence about choices tend to go well with game metaphors.

> Either choice would kill me. It was ***checkmate***.

Answer (score 10):

You don't specify, but if the scenario results from contradictory or paradoxical outcomes from either choice, you could call that a [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)).

Derived from a 1960s novel of the same name, the canonical example of catch-22 is a scenario where a pilot that wants to fly more bombing missions in a war must be insane, and therefore should not be allowed to fly, but a pilot who says he is insane and should be excused demonstrates that he is rational, and therefore must fly the bombing mission.

I also like this quote from Nanny McPhee, which could be another example: *When you need me but do not want me, then I must stay. When you want me but no longer need me, then I have to go. It's rather sad, really, but there it is.*

Comment: While an exciting application, catch-22 should be limited to when either losing choice reinforces the other, thus causing a potential loop. If I have a choice between full surrender and total annihilation, this isn't necessarily a catch 22. A catch 22, like its namesake, requires a frustrating element of irony that makes selecting either choice futile because it brings about the other.

Answer (score 7):

I think a chess term that's better than *checkmate* is [**zugzwang**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zugzwang) (which sort of hit the "mainstream" when it was used on an episode of *Criminal Minds*):

> [Oxford]
>
> A situation in which the obligation to make a move in one's turn is a serious, often decisive, disadvantage.
>
> ‘black is in zugzwang’
> ‘After a while one would realise that this position looks like a mutual zugzwang’

The difference between this and *checkmate* is that the game isn't actually over; it's simply that you are forced into making a move that is bad for you—regardless of what that move is. (With *checkmate*, you can't actually move at all . . .)

Comment: This literally translates to *forced move*, which is not quite the same as a no-win scenario. Either choice of words is going with a figurative meaning rather than its literal one. Upvoted just the same.

Comment: I don't think zugzwang really fits. The key feature of zugzwang is that one is in no immediate danger--but it's your turn to move. If you could "pass", all would be well. But the rules require that you make a move, and all of your legal moves lead to your demise. In other words, the key feature of zugzwang is not merely that there are no good choices, but that you are required to be the author of your own destruction by making a choice.

Comment: (Native AmE speaker) I've never heard of this word

Comment: I don't think most Americans have--it's very specific to chess, although I have heard it used metaphorically on occasion.

Answer (score 6):

***...a losing proposition***

[-Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/losing)

or

**...*not  a proposition***

> Unlikely to succeed; not a viable option.,
>   
>   -[Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proposition)

Not a single word; I am not sure if there is a good one. But you could say,

> "It would make no difference to choose X over Y, they would both kill me. It was ***a losing proposition***/ ***not a proposition***."

Comment: Along similar lines, *a lost cause*.

Answer (score 3):

You say you want a “less metaphorical” term, so how about **it was death either way**

Comment: All of the other answers about "no-win" or "lose-lose" still follow the *game* metaphor. This straightforward answer is a great non-metaphorical option.

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially, **damned if you do, damned if you don't** could work depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

Predicament, quandary or dilemma. Though none of these indicate a complete no win situation.

Comment: I think dilemma's definition fits the OP's question very well, **and** it's a single word. You could improve this answer by including definitions and sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid 'game over' because that phrase dates the dialog as being within the last 30 years or so, how about this:

> It was curtains.

or to avoid a metaphor altogether while still conveying the starkness of the choices on offer, how about:

> It was futile.

Answer (score 1):

It was a **fait accompli**.

From Google:

> fait ac·com·pli
>
> /ˌfed əkämˈplē,ˌfād əkämˈplē/
>
> noun
>
> a thing that has already happened or been decided before those affected hear about it, leaving them with no option but to accept.
>
> "the results were presented to shareholders as a fait accompli"

Answer (score 1):

There are many expressions that could fill in that blank.  One of the most literal is, **no-win scenario**.

Answer (score 1):

If looking for a single word or phrase, ***death sentence*** seems like a just fit here.

> It would make no difference to choose X over Y, they would both kill me. Either way, it was a *death sentence*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/death_sentence) defines **death sentence** as

*(figuratively) Anything that spells death.*

Eg: Having the Huntington's gene is a death sentence.